# How to Schedule days and hours for every two minutes trigger in Azure Logic app?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, schedule, azure-http-trigger

1. Every two mins it should get a trigger for 3 hours.
2. Run the logic app every day at 9 am?
   [image]

The above logic app triggers and runs for every 2 min.
how to set timing(3hrs) and for each day(every day) at 9 am?

eg: 10 Sep 2020 at 9 am to 12  should run, every 2 min trigger and finishs the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change `Frequency` From `Minute` to `Day`, then cilk `Add new parameter` to add `At these hours` and `At these minutes`.

Because `At these minutes` cannot use cron expressions, you can only follow the format of `0,2,4,6.....58` to make it execute every two minutes.

[image]

If you have any other questions, please let me know.